# Create a Google entry, while indexing is disabled

Tags: seo, google

I have disabled indexing on my website. I don't want any details on Google. However now, I would like to have an entry on Google, so that if someone searches, they can find me by my "firstname lastname". Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Promasters SE.  I find it difficult to understand what you are asking - you may want to edit your question with more specifics.  (Are you saying that previously you have asked Google not to Index your site, but you are now wanting Google to only partially index your site for inquiries on your name only?  If so, I posit that is not possible, although you may be able to organise your site such that Google only indexes some content [ including your name ], which could partially move you towards your goals.)

Comment: @davidgo Ok, I'll try to clarify. I would like to have the following situation: completely prevent Google from indexing my website, however, I would like my website (only the main address, e.g.: www.myfullname.com) to have an entry as one of Google search results, if someone looks for "myfullname" :)

Comment: Would allowing Google to index only the front page, but nothing else suffice? I posit this may be possible using robots.txt.  You can't both have Google both index your website and not.

Comment: I was thinking more like prevent indexing, yet somehow manually add the website entry, which I now see is possible via the Google Search Console. However I'm not sure, if this will work with indexing disabled.

Comment: How are you preventing indexing?   I'm fairly sure Google will not add a site if you have asked them not to index it.

Comment: <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

Answer (score 3):

No, as per https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/block-indexing you cannot do what you are asking. The `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` tag is specifically telling Google not to index the page, so it won't!

About the best you could do would be to put up a minimal page with your name and details that Google CAN index with links to your other content (ideally with `<a rel="nofollow">` tags although this is a bit redundant) -  and use `<meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow">` - then advise Google of this page.   In this way you will be able to have a reference in Google but not have the whole site indexed.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. Thank you very much.